# Show $\lvert x^{\beta}\rvert\le \lvert x \rvert^{\lvert\beta\rvert}$, for $\beta$ a multiindex

Tags: multivariable-calculus, index-notation

I am trying to show show that $\lvert x^{\beta}\rvert\le \lvert x \rvert^{\lvert\beta\rvert}$ where \beta is a multi-index. So I have to show $\lvert x_1^{\beta_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n^{\beta_n}\rvert \le \sqrt{(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2)}^{\lvert \beta_1+\ldots+\beta_n\rvert}$. Should I show this by induction or is there a more straight-forward way?

I am stuck in the induction :
$\lvert x_1^{\beta_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n^{\beta_n}\rvert^2\lvert x_{n+1}^{\beta_{n+1}}\rvert^2 \le(x_1^2+\ldots +x_n^2)x_{n+1}^{2\beta_{n+1}}$

Comment: *Hint:* Start with the “weighted AM-GM inequality”

Comment: Thank you, I will try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this directly, using the [weighted AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality) and the
Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Set $w_i = \frac{\beta_i}{|\beta|}$. Then $\sum w_i =1$ and therefore
$$
 |x_1|^{w_1} \cdots |x_n|^{w_n} \le w_1 |x_1| + \ldots + w_n |x_n| \\
 \le \sqrt{w_1^2 + \ldots + w_n^2}  \sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2}\\
\le  \sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2}\, .
$$
The last inequality holds because
$$
\sqrt{w_1^2 + \ldots + w_n^2} \le \sqrt{w_1 + \ldots + w_n} = 1 \, .
$$

Comment: Very nice, thank you!

Comment: @roi_saumon: You are welcome!